# FFmpeg concat produces longer output compared to the combination of all segments

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation, aac

I have around 96 `.aac` files in a directory that I want combined to produce an `output.aac` file. Similarly, I have 96 `.ts` segments to pair with the audio file. The `.ts` files produce an output of 9 minutes and 30 seconds. However, when using the following command, the `.aac` concat produces an output of 15 minutes.

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:1.aac|2.aac|3.aac" -c copy output.aac
```

I simplified the number of `.aac` segments in the command to make it easier to read.

Why would this be happening and how I can overcome this issue?

Comment: Make sure all inputs have the same channel layout/channel count and sample rate.

Comment: @llogan Is there a way for me to specify this in a command? Such as only concatenating those of the same channels, or do I need to manually go through them?

Comment: You would have to use if/then in a script with ffprobe to help you determine channel and sample rate. Something like `ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=channels,sample_rate -of default=nw=1 input.aac` Otherwise, use the aformat filter and the concat filter, but this will re-encode the audio. I assumed you wanted to avoid that.

Comment: llogan's comment saved my day. It was 44100 vs 48000 kHz audio